Remote/Lan application can not connect to android app running in emulator
My android application (similar to an ftp server but diff protocol) is running/debuged in android studio's emulator on my "Dev machine" . The dev machine is Ubuntu 22.04.The android app listens on port 9999
Another application is running on Windows machine on LAN and it has to connect to the android application mentioned above,
On "dev machine" I have forwared the port to emulator like this
  adb forward 7777 9999

The application in windows connects to my "Dev Machine" via its LAN ip address 192.168.18.14 and port 7777
Unfortunately no connection was received in the android app, firewalls are disabled.
I have tested following scenarios.
If On dev machine I use netcat to send data locally on port 7777 then android app received a connection.
Similarly if I use netcat on "Dev Machine" to listen on port 7777 , window's application can successfully connect to dev machine on it's port 7777
However the windows application running on other machine can not connect to android app in emulator.
Any help would be appreciate.

So you are trying to connect to your app running on an Android Emulator from a second Windows machine (initiator) rather than have the Android app connect (initiator) to the second Windows machine? Just making sure you've seen: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#consoleredir

I have seen it, this was not helpful,

I would expect that the forwarded port on PC side is only opened on localhost, therefore other PCs can not connect. Usually Android developers don't need or use adb forward to open a public port, therefore it is only opened on localhost.
